# Get the site_id of the user_id in Django?

Tags: django, mezzanine

I'm really struggled by this. I looked through the Django documentation and I couldn't find a method to get the `site_id` of the currently logged in `user_id` with **Sites framework**.

I want to build a blogpost form and I wan't to include the `site_id` so that the content that the user publish will go to that particular `site_id`.

The user will only have permissions to publish to one site_id.

**To clarify:**

- Publish content to the `site_id` that the user_id belongs to.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A user does not belong to a site. A request does.

If, somehow, in your Django project sites are owned by users, then you should add a new field to your `User` model. Something like this:

```
class MyUserModel(...):
    ...
    blog = models.OneToOneField(Site)
```

Comment: I don't know if it's much different from Django and Mezzanine regarding the Sites object. But In Mezzanine I have to add the users manually in the admin area and when I hit the save button a new record to the database is created. I have the tables `core_sitepermission` and `core_sitepermission_site` and in my `blog_blogpost` table I have the columns `site_id` and `user_id`.

Comment: @Y7da: you lack a field (or table) that links each user to his own blog/site. Django does not give that for you, the sites framework is not meant for that. You should manually add that field somewhere